# Lacan: a void at the heart of the subject

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, subjectivity, lacan

Can anybody explain what this Lacan's dictum exactly is?

extract from book Art and Psychoanalysis by Maria Walsh:

... Lacan’s dictum that there is a void at the heart of the subject that we fill with signifiers which
communicate with one another rather than express our intimate sense of being.

Comment: You may have a look at the Lacan entry in Stanford Encycl. Of Philoosphy.

Comment: I don't know Lacan but it looks like he endorses the Perennial view of subjects and objects. Kant also proposes that the origin of our intellectual function is 'not an instance of a category', thus a conceptual void. It's the 'thing-in-itself' argument extended to subjects as well as objects. If you practice apperception you'll find this void. .    .

Comment: I never could understand him. Maybe Slavoj Žižek can explain him to me.